# How to set Text for TextView so that it will appear from Top left through Code in Android

Tags: android

How to set Text for TextView so that it will appear from Top left through Code in Android not by XML.

Thanks in Advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView text = new TextView(context);
text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP);
```

The class `Gravity` belongs to the `android.view` package.